# Отправка формы GET на русском языке

Tags: html, javascript, form

У меня есть форма GET, которая обрабатывается с помощью Javascript. Она отправляет данные на определённый файл (например, 'act.html'). В этой форме только одно текстовое поле, в котором я пишу имя на русском языке. Почему когда файл 'act.html' получает форму, то, к примеру, вместо слова 'имя' он пишет '%C8%EC%FF'? Можно ли избавиться от этого?

Comment: отправляй форму методом POST :)

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/questions/399211/html-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-php
Увы, не могу.

Comment: Разве можно отправлять форму на html файл?! Charset указываете?

Comment: Уже не помню. Так давно было. Я тогда новичком был. А теперь я уже не занимаюсь такой фигнёй))

Answer (score 1):

Получается проставя закодированная урл строка, а чтобы прочитать можно воспользоватся встроенной функцией декодирования урл **decodeURI(var)**

потестить можно здесь:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_decodeuricomponent

Comment: почему заминусили ? проверьте решение !!!

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, в адресной строке это останется, но если получать его `$_GET['...']`, то, скорее всего, будет нормальный русский язык, либо попробуй поменять кодировку, что маловероятно поможет.

Comment: В моей форме все данные отправляются через Javascript: document.getElementById("form").submit(); . И принимаются в файле 'act.html' таким же образом: get["txt"]; . Я говорю это к тому, что язык PHP на моём сайте не поддерживается. А Javascript русские буквы увы не понимает.

Comment: кодировка будет разной если с одной в другую раскладку отправлять слова в одной кодировке!!! а если она закодировалась, то она в любой кодировке разкроется !